# How to perform Autoscaling with Azure diagnostics running in both Staging and Production?

Tags: azure, production-environment, staging, azure-diagnostics

I have set up Azure autoscaling based on Azure diagnostics of my website.

Since Staging and Production are just exact copies of each other, both Staging and Production store diagnostics to the SAME WadPerformanceCountersTable.

While I know I can differentiate between Staging and Production slots by using the DeploymentId, does Azure autoscaling make this differentiation as well? If so, how?

If not, how do I set up Azure Diagnostics and Autoscaling to only Autoscale Production based only on Production data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I ran another test which scaled with a reactive rule for both production and staging. The Autoscaler can differentiate between staging and production. I would assume it can differentiate between different deployments as well.

However the information in this post is useful for anyone who wants to remotely control diagnostics for multiple sites.

---

I do not believe Azure Autoscaling differentiates between Production and Staging, let alone different sites.  My reasoning is that I was able to autoscale one website using diagnostics from a completely different website.

As for how to differentiate between Staging and Production, here are some definitions to help make sense of the following answer:

- Autoscaler = worker role doing the autoscaling
- Target Site = the site to be scaled

Originally, I thought I would have to call on the [Azure Service Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) within my Target Site to periodically check if it was staging or not.  This is not a good answer because it is best practice to ensure that production and staging are EXACTLY the same.

Then I realized I could ["disable" diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432992.aspx) on the sites remotely by editing their diagnostic configurations to stop gathering data in my Autoscaler. The autoscaler would know which deployments were staging and production based on their deploymentId.  Using this information, we can easily switch diagnostics on or off by setting it to the default configuration.